# FileProvider is opening a PDF but it is blank. Why?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-file, android-fileprovider

I have a `FileProvider` in my app, and it pretends like it is working but the files it opens are blank.  I have confirmed that the file is already on the device in the specified directory and is not blank, but when I try to open it from inside my app it fails.  There is no crash and no error message.  Has anyone seen this before?

FileProvider:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.my.redacted.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_storage" path="." />
</paths>
```

The code:

```
    var path = "/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/User/attachments/folder/attachment.pdf"
    var file = new Java.IO.File(path);
    var mime = MimeTypeMap.Singleton;
    var ext = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(path).ToLower();
    var type = mime.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);

    var intent = new Intent();
    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
    var name = activity.PackageName + ".provider";
    var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(activity.ApplicationContext, name, file);
    intent.SetDataAndType(uri, type);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);

    var packageManager = activity.PackageManager;
    if (intent.ResolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
        activity.RunOnUiThread(() => activity.StartActivity(intent));
    else
    {
        var message = "No viewer for attachments: " + type;
        activity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            Snackbar.Make(view, message, Snackbar.LengthLong).Show()
        );
    }
```

I have debugged to see what the URI ends up being, and it looks right:

uri.Path:

```
"/external_storage/MyApp/User/attachments/folder/attachment.pdf"
```

uri.ToString():

```
"content://com.my.redacted.provider/external_storage/MyApp/User/attachments/folder/attachment.pdf"
```

So I am really not sure what is going on.

NOTE:  I DO have my documents in /storage/emulated/0/MY_STUFF and I did check to make sure that this is what `<external-path>` was returning.

Comment: `new Java.IO.File(path);`. Show the value of path please.

Comment: I added what the path is at that point to my question.  The path does have the external directory as part of it.

Comment: Also tell the values of uri.getPath() and uri.toString() please.

Comment: `but when I try to open it from inside my app it fails`. Indeed you could use the uri to open the file within your app. But you are not doing that. Instead you use an intent to let the user choose a pdf reader app. Please clarify.

Comment: I added the requested uri parameters.  I am trying to open it FROM inside my app, not open the file inside my app.  As in, I click on the file inside of my app and it launches the pdf viewer.  Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: You should call setFlags() only once as only the last one will have effect. OR the flags!

Comment: So which app is it that cannot display the pdf? Blame that app! Try more pdf viewer apps. There are plenty.

Comment: The app CAN display the pdf, it displays it just fine when I open it from the file explorer.

Comment: Can be. Maybe the file explorer offers a file system path to it. But now you offer it a content scheme path. Are you shure the viewer can handle a content scheme? Try other apps.

Comment: Welp. Feel free to post that as the answer. Apparently Google Drive can't handle content URIs. Which is kind of ridiculous. Downloaded Google PDF Viewer and it works fine. There goes 3 hours of my life...

Comment: Use `intent.addFlags` instead of `intent.setFlags`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file explorer offers a file system path to it. But now you offer it a content scheme path. Are you shure the viewer can handle a content scheme? Try other apps.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. No pdf reader could open my file provided from `FileProvider`.

My solution was adding the flag GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Maybe your fault was overriding the `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` in your code:

```
intent.setFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
intent.setFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission); <- overrides the 1st flag
```

Comment: Use `intent.addFlags` instead of `intent.setFlags`.

Comment: `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` works like a charm, thanks!